# Documentation on Windows NT Architecture (Updated)

Tags: windows, architecture

I'm trying to find some reliable documentation the architecture of Windows NT. I've found the Wikipedia page, however I'm not entirely sure how reliable that is given the "citation needed" warnings it contains. I've also found [an article on Microsoft TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768129.aspx), but it doesn't go into a lot of detail, at least not as much as I'd like. I've also had no luck in tracking down any books with the relevant information, either as a stand alone publication on the architecture, or bundled into an application programming book.

Does anyone know where I could find information on this?

---

**Update**: I found a book that contains the information, but I can't afford to buy it and my library doesn't provide access to it. Does anyone know of a free resource when I can find what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t exactly know what you need but the official documentation to the [Windows NT Ressource Kits](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windowsnt/4/workstation/reskit/en-us/default.mspx?mfr=true) goes pretty deep into the subject. Expecially [chapter 5](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windowsnt/4/workstation/reskit/en-us/archi.mspx) is talking about the Windows NT 4.0 Workstation Architechtre. It´s a lot to read but I guess it has got all the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly older version of your book from 2005 is available for download in PDF format here:

[Microsoft Windows Internals](http://csit.udc.edu/~byu/UDC3529315/WindowsInternals-4e.pdf)